# Executing a .bat file from ASP.NET / VB.NET on the server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a batch file, for testing purposes it's called -> test.bat
the location of the file is in a Folder named scripts.

Following have I tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Server.MapPath("Scripts/test.bat"))

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C://......Scripts/test.bat"))

Dim batDir As String = Server.MapPath("C://...../Scripts/") 'And with String format()
proc = New Process()
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "test.bat"
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False 'Don't know what this is, copied it from somewhere.
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()
```

And I don't get any exception.

**Edit 1:**

My test.bat should create a folder on the Desktop (Testing purposes).

**Edit 2: I'm getting this warning in the Event Log**

---

Event code: 3001

Event message: Request was cancelled.

Event time: 21.07.2020 14:17:09

Event time (UTC): 21.07.2020 12:17:09

Event ID: 4dbd86698e044d2092a89ed01d24f418

Event sequence: 3809

Event occurrence: 4

Event detail code: 0

Application information:

```
Application domain: xxx 

Trust level: Full 

Application Virtual Path: xxx 

Application Path: C:\xxx

Machine name: xxx
```

Process information:

```
Process ID: 8388 

Process name: w3wp.exe

Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
```

Exception information:

```
Exception type: HttpException 

Exception message: Request time exceeded.
```

Request information:

```
Request URL: http://xxx\mySite.aspx 

Request path: \mySite.aspx 

User host address: xxx 

User:  

Is authenticated: False 

Authentication Type: 

Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
```

Thread information:

```
Thread ID: 138 

Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Is impersonating: False 

Stack trace:
```

Custom event details:

---

Could it be a Authentication problem?

Comment: What's in your test.bat file? What user is the web application running as? What exact folder do you try to place the file in? Does that account your app is running as have permission to execute the bat file and write to the desktop? Why are you bothering with a .bat file when you could just implement the logic directly into your web app?

Comment: @mason I was able to solve it, like I wrote as an Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the execution permission to the IIS = "APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" User and now your folder should be able to be created successfully.